# Want to adjust two divs next to each in CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: HTML AND CSS CODE]

Here is the HTML AND CSS code:

```css
div.div1 {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

div.div2 {
  width: 730px;
  height: 700px;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.div3 {
  width: 470px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 30px;
  display: block;
}

div.div4 {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.div5 {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">Hello, Header</div>
<div class="div2">Hello, Left Sidebar</div>
<div class="div3">Hello, RIGHT Sidebar Internal</div>
```

Need to adjust left and right side next to each other with CSS property. Tried to adjust it with css display property but it comes in next line always. Above is the CSS AND Html code for it. NEED left and right sidebars DIVS next to each other Please help with the code.

Comment: [F L E X](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 1):

In very simple terms, you have to remember that `div` is a block level element so it takes up all the space on that line so that the next `div` goes to the next line. Even if you give it a width as you did, that remaining space will be filled up with a margin.
As solutions, you could:

1. Use inline elements like `span` instead of `div` so that they are side by side
2. Use the property `display: inline` on the `div` to make it inline so that width can apply to it the way you want and they elements go side by side
3. Or Use `flexbox` as directed by the first answer...

Answer (score 1):

you can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) something like this, i am also beginner
here also a game to learn more about flexbox  [Game](https://flexboxfroggy.com/#de) it helped me alot to learn

```
    <style>
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
  }
  .div1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  .div2 {
    width:50%;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: red;
  }

  div.div3 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: green;
  }
```

---

```
 <div class="div1">Hello, Header</div>
      <main class="container">
          <div class="div2">Hello, Left Sidebar</div>
          <div class="div3">Hello, RIGHT Sidebar Internal</div>
      </main>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `flexbox` or a `css grid`. Hope is this what you are looking for :

```css
body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: 70px 1fr;
  gap:2rem;
}
div.div1
{
 
   height:;
   background-color:red;
   border:1px solid black;
  

}

main{
  display : grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr;
  gap: 3rem
}
div.div2
{   
   
   background-color:red;
   border:1px solid black;
   
  
  
}
    div.div3
{
   background-color:red;
   border:1px solid black;
    display:block;
    

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Web Page Design</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="div1">Hello, Header</div>
  <main>
    <div class="div2">Hello, Left Sidebar</div>
<div class="div3">Hello, RIGHT Sidebar Internal</div>
  </main>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can anybody explain why there is always a white blank between  tags when we add some text in it. Anyway, to create multicolumn layout, you can refer here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp there are some useful examples to learn and practice there.

Comment: Please don't ask questions in the answer section. Create a new question instead.